# Path for contact form file

Tags: php, paths

I have a php contact form that I use with all websites, so ideally I want to avoid using a plug in. The files used include:

• contact.php - A file with php/html write up which displays the form fields.

• contact-form.php - A file that contact.php connects to to send the information.

I've created the equivalent of contact.php as a static page in the Wordpress login.

The code within contact.php which connect to contact-form.php is as follows:

```
<form method="post" action="/contact-form.php" >
```

What I would like to know is how I would connect to this file in the instance of Wordpress - locating files in Wordpress is something which has always confused me...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could put both the form and processing logic in the same file and submit the form to the same page by omitting the action attribute. Check $_POST vars to see if the form has been submitted and do your processing, otherwise display the form.

```
if( isset( $_POST['somevar'] ) ) :
    // process submission
else :
    // show form
endif;
```

Comment: I may be mistaken but I don't think static pages (in Wordpress login) accept php?

Comment: you would [create a page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates) specific to your page and add the code there, or create your own [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) to add the form to a page.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand these options... I'm still pretty new to this so for me it's like a can of worms for a simple function.

Comment: your theme renders each page with a template following the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Page_display). when you're editing a page, you can select a custom template that will display that page on the front end. see the link above for info on creating that template, start with your theme's `page.php` template and duplicate then edit it.

Comment: Ok I've done this, thanks. To do with the if statement above, how would I get this to work. I understand your logic but I can't seem to get it to work, whenever I click submit on the form for the data to be sent and validated it just returns the form...

Comment: What did you change the if statement to check? Without seeing your form and the names of the form elements, I can't tell you what to change it to. Alternately, you can check `if( !empty( $_POST ) )` to see if any post vars are set. This isn't unique to WordPress, just basic PHP form handling.

Comment: Again I apologise for my lack of knowledge, but I don't understand what the if statement needs to check?

Comment: you're checking if the form has been submitted or if it's just a normal page load. if the form has been submitted, post vars corresponding to your form's fields will be set, and you'll know that you need to run the form processing logic. if the post vars don't exist, the form should be displayed.